# How to lock row if a cell has a value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an Excel worksheet that should be open for several users.

It's important that no one write over what is already written.

Is there a way to automatically lock a row once the person has finished editing?

Before locking the row, changes in column B, D, F, G and H should be allowed.

For example: If there is a value in cell A5; then A5 to H5 should be locked, but open if there are no value in cell A5. This "rule" must work for all rows from A5 to A'XXX'.

Comment: Look at `For Each` loops, and the `Range.Locked` property.  You can use "Record Macro" from the Developer tab to get some basic code, and press F1 with code selected to get the help pages

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution involving the events `Worksheet_SelectionChange` (to track the previous value) and `Worksheet_Change` (to compare it to the changed value). I've tried to accommodate multi-cell selections, but it doesn't seem to play particularly nicely with larger selections.

Enter it into the worksheet's macro code – it won't work at workbook-level or as a module.

```
Dim previousValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    previousValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
      Dim i As Long, j As Long
      For i = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
          Target(i, j) = previousValue(i, j)
        Next j
      Next i
      GoTo Cleanup
      Exit Sub
    End If
    If previousValue <> "" Then
        Target.Value = previousValue
    End If
Cleanup:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Do consider, though, that users make mistakes entering data and probably won't appreciate being prevented from correcting those mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked great. Is it any way that I, as document owner, can change the cells or do I have to delete/turn this of if I want to do some corrections?

Comment: You could check the value of `Environ("Username")` against your username, and only execute the rest of the function if they're not equal. A savvy user will be able to find away around this, but they've probably already disabled the macro anyway.